# What is the minimum degree of a 4-regular graph of diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory

What is the minimum degree of a four-regular graph of diameter 2.

From trial and error I have concluded that the minimum degree is six.
Explanation: If I start from one node then there must be 4 edges off this and each one of these edges must have a node attached to it, this gives us 5 nodes. Since the graph has diameter 2 I have to add a sith node to achieve this. Connecting these nodes with various edges will result in them all having degree four.

How would one rigorously justify this though?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is fine to show that the degree must be at least six.  If you draw a graph the way you describe, you can show that you can meet the requirement with a graph of degree six, so you are done.  It is $K_6$ with three edges deleted.  The three edges connect disjoint pairs of vertices.  It is also the skeleton of the octahedron.